# Issues reading in file with fgetc C

Tags: c, fgetc

So I'm writing a parallelized sudoku solution checker in C, but I seem to be encountering an issue with reading in a plain old .txt file.

Here is the code to read in the file:

```
FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file\n");
    return 1;
}

//Begin copying file using fgetc
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    for (int i = 0; i < PUZZLE_SIZE; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < PUZZLE_SIZE; ++j) {
            if (c != -38) { //-38 is newline
                //puzzle is a global array of ints
                puzzle[i][j] = c - 48; //handles ASCII to int (1-9) conversion
            }
        }
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

The .txt file is as follows:

```
534678912
672195348
198342567
859761423
426853791
713924856
961537284
287419635
345286179
```

When I print c - 48, I get the expected values; when I print puzzle[i][j] inside of the loops, I get the normal values again. However, when I look at my puzzle array afterward, every value is set to 9; I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why. Is there a memory/scoping issue that I'm not aware of?

Comment: `if (c != -38) { //-38 is newline` I cincerely doubt that -->  `if (c != '\n') { ...}` Also `puzzle[i][j] = c - 48;` --> `puzzle[i][j] = c - '0';` Btw `if (c == '\n) break;` is clearer and more robus and avoids the nesting.

Comment: Due to the surrounding while you execute both for loops for every character in the file, on every cell of the grid, and the last char in the file happens to be a 9...  You'll need to review your loop logic.

Comment: The return value from `fgetc()` will either be a non-negative integer in the range 0..UCHAR_MAX (usually 255) or EOF (usually -1).  It will not be -38 under any known circumstances.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Well, numbers don't work that way, either you're using `char`, which is signed, so you can have any value between -128 and 127, either you're using `unsigned char` which can only contain numbers from 0 to 255.

Comment: @Pillsy The edit in the code could have fixed the problem and should not have been approved.  Rollback is the proper action.

Comment: @Taiki Wrong. In the specific case of `fgetc()`, the man pages explicitly say that it returns the value of a char casted to `unsigned char`, or EOF. It works that way because `EOF` is always negative; this allows implementations which use negative chars to cope with this - otherwise, `EOF` could be wrongly interpreted as a valid character. So, `fgetc()` always returns a positive value, or a negative constant denoting `EOF`.

Comment: @Taiki Avoid making edits in code.  You may be fixing the error that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Taiki: au contraire.  ISO/IEC 9899:2011 7.21.7.1 **The `fgetc` function** says: _[...] the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned
char` converted to an `int`[...]_  (An implementation could legitimately use -38 as EOF, but no known implementation does that.)

Comment: EOF (-1) is represented in binary like that: 11111111, which is the same representation than 255. Try it: ((char) -1 == (char) 255). You can set a char to any value, 255 like -38, but the result will depend of if you interpret the value as signed or unsigned

Comment: @Taiki `c` is an int, not a char. The return type from fgetc() is also an int.

Comment: @Taiki: there are so many misconceptions and problems in that statement it is painful.  Suffice to say, I disagree with your analysis.

Comment: @Taiki If you assume 2 complement, yes. But for 255, note that when promoted to `int` it will contain leading zeros, contrary to what happens with `-1`.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: c is an int, not a char. The return type from fgetc() is also an int. Nothing is promoted here.

Comment: @wildplasser Hemm, wrong choice of word. I didn't mean promotion in the technical sense.

Comment: Didn't saw c was an int... never mind then, I thought the code partially worked because -38 underflowed to a somehow legit value...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, what your program does is:  For every character in the file (`while`), set ALL (`for`, `for`) puzzle entries to that character.  As a result, all entries will contain the file's last character.

You want to put the `for` loops on the outside and read one character per puzzle entry instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PUZZLE_SIZE; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < PUZZLE_SIZE; ++j) {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if (c == '\n')
            c = fgetc(fp); // get a new char if we hit a newline
         puzzle[i][j] = c - `0`;
    }
```

This is assuming that there are enough characters in the file to fill the puzzle.

Comment: You could strengthen the testing. In the inner loop, if the character is not a digit, it is an error. After the inner loop (but before the end of the outer loop), you could read the next character; if it is not a newline, it is an error.

Comment: Good ideas.  I definitely recommend implementing them.  However, for this answer, I only intend to address the original problem without adding functionality.